# Can Antimatter undergo nuclear fission/fusion?

Tags: nuclear-physics, antimatter, fusion

I was curious if antimatter could undergo nuclear fission/fusion with other antimatter. It makes sense, I was wondering if it would work?

Answer (score 3):

Almost all particles are believed to behave identically between matter and anti-matter - in fact a number of Nobel prizes were awarded for finding the few exceptions.

So as far as we know *anti* hydrogen- *anti* hydrogen fusion should work just the same

Anti-matter fission is probably a little way off, it's going to take quite a bit of money/time/energy to make a critical mass of anti-Uranium 235

Comment: The STAR experiment detected anti-helium, so, although it's not uranium, it classifies as an multi-anti-barion bound state, formed by 'fusion' to an certain extent.

Comment: If you are looking for energy production, anti-matter fission or fusion would provide far LESS energy than merely mixing matter with anti-matter.