# What would happen if you split an antimatter nucleus?

Tags: nuclear-physics, antimatter

If we had the huge money required to make it, could it be used as a weapon more destructive than a regular nuclear bomb? Here it would undergo fission AND annihilate regular particles, so...?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106632/

Comment: That doesn't explain how it would be more effective

Comment: "Effective" in this case is more of a term from economics. One can't beat the effectiveness of conventional thermonuclear weapons with any known technology. They are "dead" simple (once you know how to make them right) and dirt cheap to make (for the amount of stuff they destroy). Can one make an antimatter bomb? Sure. It would be absolutely cumbersome, horrifically unreliable (i.e. you would be blowing yourself up ten times before you would hit the enemy once) and it would be enormously expensive... as in... nobody can afford one expensive.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Please take the [tour] and look around. We do expect some level of work before posting, such as how much energy is produced in a fission even, and how much in particle-antiparticle annihilation. Please edit to clarify the physics question at the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy released by the fission of an antimatter bomb would be minuscule compared to the energy released when the antimatter interacts with matter. How much smaller?

According to [wikipedia's article on nuclear fission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission),

> Typical fission events release about two hundred million eV (200 MeV) of energy for each fission event

Now the mass (equivalent energy) of a single proton is about 938 MeV; if you could convert all the mass of particles in a "anti" U-235 to energy by annihilation, it would produce more than 1000x more energy than the fission itself.

So there really is no point in attempting the complexity you consider. The fission would do a damage of 1; the subsequent annihilation would release 1000x more energy. If you could just make and contain a spoonful of antimatter, it will do incredible amounts of damage. See for example "Angels and Demons" by Dan Brown. That's the crux of the story (which is full of holes on the physics side, but that's another story).

Comment: How much does a spoonful of antimatter cost these days?

Comment: @CuriousOne - if you have to ask, you can't afford it.

Comment: Touché! I can't, indeed. :-)